# How to implement tab-pane change function in intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-bootstrap

How to implement [jQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978977/change-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-automatically/19905256#19905256) function that plays with angular-bootstrap? I would like to implement play button and turn on tabs carousel from selected to the last tab.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tab 1",
    message: "",
    active: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Tab 2",
    message: "",
    active: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tab 3",
    message: "",
    active: false
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
    </button>
    <tabset>
      <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.name}}" active="tab.active">
        {{tab}}
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why jQuery solution? you don't want to write the event handler in controller? Any specific reasons for this?

Comment: @VinayK link fixed, I mean what is the best way, controller or perhaps directive or avoid jquery and use jqLite?

Comment: The best practice for this case is writing a directive.

Comment: I also included a quick-and-dirty solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution. Best practice for this case is writing a directive.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tab 1",
    message: "",
    active: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Tab 2",
    message: "",
    active: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tab 3",
    message: "",
    active: false
  }];
  
  var i = 0, interval;
  
  $scope.play = function() {
    $interval.cancel(interval);
    interval = $interval(function() {
        $scope.tabs[i].active = false;
        $scope.tabs[i++].active = true;
        i = i%3;  
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <button ng-click="play()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
    </button>
    <tabset>
      <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.name}}" active="tab.active">
        {{tab}}
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could find more info and guidance from this page: https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/the-8020-guide-to-writing-angularjs-directives/